# Why does my computer not always get to BIOS screen any more?

Tags: laptop, boot, bios

I've got a 5+ year old Dell XPS m1530 notebook, that has started to just give a black screen sometimes before getting to the BIOS splash screen. It happens more often than not right now, so I'm extremely hesitant/afraid to turn it off.
When it doesn't happen, everything goes swimmingly. When it does happen, one can audibly hear hdd spinning up and fans going, so it doesn't seem like a power issue.

Has anyone encountered anything like this before, or have any idea what I can do to fix it? Thanks in advance for any help! :)

Comment: I would changed the CMOS battery and see if something changes.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If it was an issue with the CMOS battery though, wouldn't the time need to be set on the occasions that it does come up? I've gotten a spare CMOS battery anyway, and I'll replace the next time I need to power off, on your suggestion. Thanks :)

Comment: The battery was failing it wasn't dead yet.  I don't really speculate in a case like this.  It was the battery it could have been simple loose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older laptops have a fluorescent backlight in the display.  This light bulb can intermittently not light.  If the screen remains black and looks like it's off completely but the system makes disk noises and sounds like it's booting, this might be your problem.  Usually you can take a flashlight and shine it on the display to see if anything is actually being displayed.  Alternately, it could be that the electronics in the display are failing, although a bad bulb is more common when the problem is intermittent.  Try connecting an external monitor when this problem occurs, and pressing the key combination that cycles video to the external port (should be <kbd>Fn+F8</kbd> if Google shows the right keyboard).  If the external port always works, then you'll probably just need to replace the display.

If it's not a display issue, then things get much harrier.  The BIOS splash is typically part of the POST (Power-On Self Test).  In order for a system to complete the AT style POST, it generally needs the following:

1. Motherboard
2. CPU
3. Memory
4. Video device (not a monitor, just the device that sends the signal to a monitor)

Not all systems require a video device but they should according to the spec as I recall. These components are the only required components to POST a computer.  Therefore, it logically follows that if a computer doesn't complete the POST that one of the above components is failing, damaged, or missing.

You can try to reseat the RAM or replace it, or verify that the CPU is not working its way out of the socket.  If you've got two brands of RAM in use, remove the second SO-DIMM so that you've only got one.

Ultimately the only way to go from there is to start replacing parts.  If it's not the display or the memory, it's most likely the motherboard (or, since this is a laptop, main board and daughterboard).  CPUs almost never fail, and I've never seen one fail intermittently.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've ruled out that it's a display issue, since I always use an external monitor. I've also ruled out memory (I had some working spares so I switched it). I unfortunately think you might be right in thinking that it's a main board issue. It seems like if I leave the machine idle for a long enough period, it will then work. Thanks again for your reply (I haven't got enough reputation to upvote)!